# Display UIView's instead of Images with OpenFlow

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using [OpenFlow](http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/) in my iPad application.  I want to display my UIView's instead of images - to allow the user to flick through different 'detail' views?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to display images of the views then when the user selects an Image, simply display the appropriate view. You could even programmatically take a screenshot to ensure the images displayed in OpenFlow are up to date.

See [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/149553#149553) on a way to do this.

Comment: dude . . i am not a member in apple developer forums . . can you help me and put up what is written in the link ?